# Request() vs Request.QueryString()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have recently started using `Request("key")` instead of `Request.QueryString("key")` to access my querystring values. However I have read that:

> Gets the specified object from the System.Web.HttpRequest.Cookies,
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.Form, System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString,
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables

Therefore, if I have a querystring key and cookie key which are the same, which value is returned?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're checked in the following order:

1. `QueryString`
2. `Form`
3. `Cookies`
4. `ServerVariables`

The search is short-circuited, so as soon as a matching key is found the value is returned.

So, to answer your question, a matching `QueryString` item takes precedence over `Cookies`.

Comment: For more information, see Scott Hanselman's excellent blog post on this a while ago at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx

Comment: Thanks Luke. The only problem I see with using this is that if I was to do an If Statement on whether or not a querystring existed, using 'request' would return true if a cookie of the same name existed. Therefore I think I'll stick with 'Request.Querystring'. Plus, it'll be useful for other developers to know straight away exactly where this information is being requested from. However, it's good to know that this short-hand way is available for future use, cheers.