# Request versus Request.QueryString

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

What is the difference between these two in VBScript:

```
Request("startDate")

Request.QueryString["startDate"]
```

And where is `Request("startDate")` documented? I don't see this usage here:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp

Comment: Your question has been answered however an appropriate piece advice has not be offered.  That is:  Don't use `Request("name")`. Always explicitly use the collection required.  Why MS ever included this "shortcut" I can't fathom, it just leads to confusion, abiguity and uncertainy, oh and questions like this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request() vs Request.QueryString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178536/request-vs-request-querystring)

Comment: Dup! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178536/request-vs-request-querystring

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The official documentation for the `Request` object in ASP classic is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28VS.90%29.aspx

Quoting the relevant part for this question:

> All variables can be accessed directly by calling Request(variable)
>   without the collection name. In this case, the Web server searches the
>   collections in the following order:
>
> - QueryString
> - Form
> - Cookies
> - ClientCertificate
> - ServerVariables
>
> If a variable with the same name exists in more than one collection,
>   the Request object returns the first instance that the object
>   encounters.

---

EDIT: AnthonyWJones made a great comment on the question: Avoid using the `Request("name")` syntax.  In fact, this is mentioned in the documentation link above:

> It is strongly recommended that when referring to members of a
>   collection the full name be used. For example, rather than
>   **Request**.("AUTH_USER") use **Request.ServerVariables**("AUTH_USER"). This
>   allows the server to locate the item more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

See [Request() vs Request.QueryString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178536/request-vs-request-querystring)

From what I understand when you use Request on it's own it will return the first matched item in the request collection. well explained in the attached solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to dredge up this question, but given the warnings against using Request("param"), I had to add my two cents. In this particular case there's a good reason to use Request("param") instead of Request.QueryString("param"): It allows you to write code that will accept parameters as part of a query string or when submitted through a form. I regularly run into situations where that is not only handy, but desirable.

Comment: You make an excellent point, but this really should be a comment, not an answer.