# QueryString always returns null in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use facebook share feature to share image url and return the user back to same page if click on the image on facebook.

I have some backend logic in place where user will be redirected to the page after some prosessing is done on ImageShare.aspx page

Below is a sample url when sharing

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com/ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg&slide=1&lg=1&pageurl=http://domain.com/photo/2016/album-images`

CODE

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbMetaDetails = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
string urlReferer;
string pageURL=null;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
pageURL = Request["pageurl"] + "#lg=1&slide=" + Request["slide"];
.....
.....
.....
}
```

`Request["pageurl"] AND Request["slide"]` URL always return null. I am not sure why this is happening.

I am not able to figure out why i get null for these values `Request["pageurl"] AND Request["slide"]`

UPDATE:

I noticed that problem doesnt seems to be querystring. when i checked the source of form it show it it show action url only with img query string
`<form method="post" action="./ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg" id="form1">`

I am trying to pass following url to facebook `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com/ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg&slide=1&lg=1&pageurl=http://domain.com/photo/2016/album-images`

but my og:url tags are not as i want them to be. source of teh page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><meta property='og:image' content='http://www.domain.com/Images/gallery/images/f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.JPG'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the image'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description of teh image'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='#lg=1&slide='/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='http://www.domain.com'/>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="1F8C24FB" />
</div>
    <div>

    </div>
        <img id="ImgName" src="http://www.domain.com/Images/gallery/images/f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Complete Code for the page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using CMS.DataAccessLayer;
using CMS.SqlHelper;
using CMS.DateConvertion;
using CMS.BusinessObjects;
using CMS.DataAccessLayer;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class ImageShare2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       showDetails();

    }



    public void showDetails()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


            var img = Request["img"];

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(img))
            {
                String strSql = "SELECT * FROM PhotoAlbumImages WHERE PhotoImageLarge ='" + img + "'";
                ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                int rCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                int ctr = 0;
                var Title = String.Empty;
                string  imgURL = String.Empty;
                ImgName.ImageUrl = "http://www.Domain.com/Images/gallery/images/" + img;
                //ogImage.Content = "~/Images/gallery/images/" + img;


                System.Text.StringBuilder sbMetaDetails = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                string urlReferer;
                string pageURL=null;

                //Response.Write("<br/><br/>Request.UrlReferrer : " + Request.UrlReferrer +"<br/>");

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
                {

                   // urlReferer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower();

                    //pageURL = Helper.GetQueryStringValue("purl");
                    //Response.Write("Helper.GetQueryStringValue('pageurl')<br> " + Request.QueryString["pageurl"]);
                    pageURL = Request.QueryString["pageurl"] + "#lg=1&slide=" + Request.QueryString["slide"];
                    //BUILD Redirect URL




                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Title = dr["PhotoTitle"].ToString();

                        imgURL = "http://www.Domain.com/Images/gallery/images/" + dr["PhotoImageLarge"].ToString();

                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:image' content='" + imgURL + "'/>");
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>");
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:title' content='" + Title + "'/>");
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:description' content='" + dr["PhotoDesc"].ToString() + "'/>");
                        //sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "'/>");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageURL))
                        {
                            sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + pageURL + "'/>");                           
                            Response.Write("AA<br>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "'/>");
                            Response.Write("AB<br>");
                        }
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:site_name' content='http://www.Domain.com'/>");
                    }

                    litCtrMetaForSM.Text = sbMetaDetails.ToString();

                    //redirect
                    //Response.Redirect(pageURL);

                }
                else
                {

                    urlReferer = "";
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Title = dr["PhotoTitle"].ToString();


                        imgURL = "http://www.Domain.com/Images/gallery/images/" + dr["PhotoImageLarge"].ToString();
                        // ogImage.Content = imgURL;

                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:image' content='" + imgURL + "'/>");

                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>");
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:title' content='" + Title + "'/>");
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:description' content='" + dr["PhotoDesc"].ToString() + "'/>");
                        //sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "'/>");
                        if (pageURL == null)
                        {
                            sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + Request.Url.ToString() + "'/>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:url' content='" + pageURL + "'/>");
                        }
                        sbMetaDetails.AppendLine("<meta property='og:site_name' content='http://www.Domain.com'/>");
                        litCtrMetaForSM.Text = sbMetaDetails.ToString();
                        //Response.Redirect(pageURL);
                    }
                }








            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());}

    }




}
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ImageShare.aspx.cs" Inherits="ImageShare2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <asp:Literal ID="litCtrMetaForSM" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <asp:Image ID="ImgName" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The sample url you provided at the top, how do you build them? If it is exactly as given above, then that might be the problem for query strings needs to be url encoded.

Comment: I actually pass this url to facebook for share `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://domain.com/ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg&slide=1&lg=1&pageurl=http://domain.com/photo/2016/album-images`  but i am not able to get the same url as link on facebook always shows url with img part not the whole url..

Comment: further to this url i have to apped two more querystring as `#lg=1&slide=10` value for slide is dynamic. Based on img i query database & create Title, description and want to recreate the og:url tag but it doesnt seems to work as query-string as on FB page image is linked to `http://domain.com/ImageShare.aspx?img=f3082420-8b92-4301-b093-bf8ce3f91772.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to the following:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbMetaDetails = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

string urlReferer;
string pageURL=null;

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    pageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["pageurl"] + "#lg=1&slide=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["slide"];
    .....
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: I had tried this also `i am not sure if problem is with querystring. i have updated question with more details

Answer (score 0):

There should not be an issue due to using Request[] vs Request.QueryString[] since Request[] checks for resources starting with the QueryString (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178558/4630403).

Check the browser url when the site is hitting your method and verify that "pageurl" and "slide" are present in it.

If it isn't then your form/ajax call is not sending the data with the request.

-Edit-

Please post the code from where you are coming to the ImageShare2 Page(form/link).